# Почему различается output? Была написана программа, но её надо переписать под функции

Tags: c++, строки, функции, char

[image: Задание]

```
//Пример работающей программы
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        bool flag = true;
        bool jk = false;
        char str;
        string str_output;
        while ((str = cin.get()) != '\n')
        {
            str_output += str;

        if (str == ',')
        {
            str_output.clear();
            jk = true;
        }
        if (str == '.' || str == '?' || str == '!')
        {
            if (!jk)
            {
                cout << str_output << endl;
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            str_output.clear();
            flag = true;
            jk = false;
        }
        }
    }

``
//Программа переписанная под функции
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    void logic_function(bool flag,string str_output,bool jk)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            str_output.clear();
            flag = true;
            jk = false;
        }
    }
    void logic(char str,bool jk,string str_output,bool flag)
    {

        if (str == '.' || str == '?' || str == '!')
        {
            if (!jk)
            {
                cout << str_output;
            }
            flag = false;
        }

    }
    void clear_str(string str_output,char str,bool jk)
    {
        if (str == ',')
        {
            str_output.clear();
            jk = true;
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        bool flag = true;
        bool jk = false;
        char str;
        string str_output;
        while ((str = cin.get()) != '\n')
        {
            str_output += str;
            clear_str(str_output, str, jk);
            logic(str, jk, str_output, flag);
            logic_function(flag, str_output, jk);

        }
    }
```

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/563dcf370564bb26

Comment: не скажу, что совсем дубликат, но свзязанная тема.  Интересно, чтo абсолютно такой же вопрос с точностью до ситуации и результата был на английском сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда Вы передаёте в функцию переменную как аргумент, копируется только значение переменной. Все изменения этого значения внутри функции будут локальными и никак не отразятся на основной переменной. Т.е. создали Вы переменную `flag` внутри функции `main` и передали её в какую-нибудь функцию. Эта функция изменила значение `flag`. Но после возврата в `main` значение `flag` будет прежним. Функция изменила только локальную копию значения, а, завершая работу, уничтожила эту копию, никуда не передав.
Решить эту проблему можно либо используя глобальные переменные (но это делать не рекомендуется в целях улучшения качества кода + Вам по заданию нельзя их использовать), либо возвращая значения из функций. Последнее можно делать с помощью return (не забудьте указать для функций тип возвращаемого значения), либо с помощью параметров-указателей. Но судя по уровню урока, за указатели Вам браться ещё рановато.